# What is the best practise to pick TimeSpan in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

i am making my first WP8.1 app - kitchen timer. I have TextBox as input for time span value and then parse it. So user must write timespan as raw text - unpractical as user must write numbers and colons.

I am looking for some technique, how to let user to pick time span value. In WP8, there was TimeSpanPicker in WP Toolkit. But what to use in WP8.1? I prefer some "out of box" solution.

**My ideas:**

- use 3 TextBox for hours, minutes and seconds
- use kind of real-time parsing with auto placing colons. But this is quite hard to code it.

**Is there any better (and easy) way?**

Comment: I don't use it, but this _may_ be more suited to [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you targetting *Runtime* or *Silverlight*? As for *Silverlight* you should find some usefull controls in WPToolkit. In RT, there are [TimePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308517.aspx) and [TimePickerFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepickerflyout.aspx), though there will be a problem if you need seconds and I believe you need them for kitchen timer. Therefore I would look for some kind of looping selector or something similar.

Comment: I am targeting to Runtime. I noticed there is TimePicker, but it is made to pick a daytime, not time span. I think, there is not implementation of looping selector in WP8.1. There is one in WP Toolkit, but only for WP8.